# How to copy text from command-line mode in Vim?

Tags: vim

Say, I just ran this command in Vim:

```
:nmap <CR> <C-]>
```

And now I want to copy this line and put it into my `.vimrc`.
How can I select and copy the whole line in command-line mode?

Comment: if you have already executed you can type `q:` and open a buffer with the commands, so you can copy them there as usual.

Comment: This would have been the answer for me :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The fastest way is to run the command, switch to the destination
buffer (with `.vimrc` loaded, in this case) and paste the whole
command from the `:` register by typing

```
":p
```

in Normal mode.

If the command is further back in time, one can first recall it from
history (e.g., by typing the first few letters and pressing the up
arrow key <kbd>↑</kbd>), rerun it, and then use the above method.

When these shortcuts are unhandy, one can resort to the general
approach of using the command-line window (see `:help cmdwin`).
To open it, either type `q:` in Normal mode, or press the key
combination set by the `cedit` option in Command-line mode
(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, by default).

Answer (score 15):

You can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> while in command mode to open up a special window with all previous commands.  Then you can scroll to the desired line, hit <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> to copy that line, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to return to command mode, and then <kbd>ESC</kbd> to return to normal mode.  From there you can paste.

See `:help cmdwin` for more information on the command window.

Comment: This special window is so useful! In spacemacs I am able to grab an old search by scrolling up and hitting enter! All with Vim bindings!

Comment: This is bound to `q:` for ex and `q/` for search!!!