# How to copy text from commandline mode in Vim while searching

Tags: vim

There is already a question regarding how to [copy text in commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047618/how-to-copy-text-from-commandline-mode-in-vim) in Vim. There are two alternative answers:

1. `":p`, and
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, followed by finding the previous command.

But these methods don't work when the previous command is a search. That is if I enter into command mode with `/` or `?`, then the search term used cannot be accessed with these methods.

Is there a way to copy text for search text as well?

Comment: `Ctrl`+`F` opens the command-line window for previous commands when you are entering a command, and for previous searches if you entering a search.  Another words, `:`,`Ctrl`+`F` is the same as `q:`, `/`,`Ctrl`+`F` and `?`,`Ctrl`+`F` are the same as `q/` and `q?`, respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `/` register. You can use `"/p` to paste the last search. While on the command-line you can use `<c-r>` followed by a register to insert the contents of the given register. example: `<c-r>/` will paste the last search.

You may also wish to use `q/` to do more extensive editing of your previous searches.

```
:h registers
:h q/
:h c_CTRL-R
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking the approach similar to the one proposed in the [accepted
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047618/how-to-copy-text-from-commandline-mode-in-vim/7048334#7048334) to the question “[How to copy text from commandline mode
in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047618/how-to-copy-text-from-commandline-mode-in-vim)”, one can use the `/` register to paste the most recent
search pattern:

```
"/p
```

The whole history of searches can be explored using the command-line
window (see `:help cmdwin`). To open it for editing of search strings
from Normal mode, use the `q/` or `q?` commands. To do the same when
entering a search pattern for the `/` or `?` commands, press the key
combination specified by the `cedit` option (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>,
by default).